# Semantic UI : ui error inside pushable doesnot work

Tags: css, semantic-ui

I am creating a form inside a sidebar using pushable, the HTML structure is in snippet bellow

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="ui card pushable" style="height: 82vh; padding: 0px;">
  <div class="ui segment ui overlay right wide visible sidebar" style="padding: 0px;">
    <div class="ui card">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="header">Add Merchant Group</div>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <form class="ui form">
          <div class="field"><label>Name</label>
            <div class="ui error input"><input type="text"></div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="extra content"><button class="ui blue right floated button"><i aria-hidden="true" class="user plus icon"></i>Add</button><button class="ui red right floated button">Cancel</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pusher">
    <div class="ui grid">
      <div class="one column row">
        <div class="column">
          <div class="ui raised segments">
            <div class="ui clearing segment"><button class="ui small compact right floated button light"><i aria-hidden="true" class="plus icon"></i>Add</button></div>
            <div class="ui segment" style="padding: 0px;">
              <table class="ui selectable single line table">
                <thead class="">
                  <tr class="left aligned">
                    <th class="">Name</th>
                    <th class="">Description</th>
                    <th class=""></th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="">
                  <tr class="">
                    <td class="">
                      <div class="ui transparent input"><input type="text"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="">
                      <div class="ui transparent input"><input type="text"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td class=""><button class="ui red mini icon button light"><i aria-hidden="true" class="red delete icon"></i></button></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="ui error input"><input type="text"></div>
```

as you see `<div class="ui error input"><input type="text"></div>` behaving differently inside and outside the div of pushable. The only thing that syled as error is input's placeholder, what is going wrong? should i define new rules?

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect carefully, you can see that the input outside is affected by the selector 
`.ui.error.input > input` while the input inside the form has been affected by selector `.ui.form input[type="text"]`.

They have the same specificity value, so the later will override the first selector defined rules.

You can simply wrap it in a `.form` element or adding the css I added in the snippet below

```css
.ui.error.input input[type="text"] {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95);
  border-color: #85B7D9;
  border-radius: 0.28571429rem;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0em 0em 0em rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.35) inset;
  box-shadow: 0px 0em 0em 0em rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.35) inset;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="ui card pushable" style="height: 82vh; padding: 0px;">
  <div class="ui segment ui overlay right wide visible sidebar" style="padding: 0px;">
    <div class="ui card">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="header">Add Merchant Group</div>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <form class="ui form">
          <div class="field"><label>Name</label>
            <div class="ui error input"><input type="text"></div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="extra content"><button class="ui blue right floated button"><i aria-hidden="true" class="user plus icon"></i>Add</button><button class="ui red right floated button">Cancel</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pusher">
    <div class="ui grid">
      <div class="one column row">
        <div class="column">
          <div class="ui raised segments">
            <div class="ui clearing segment"><button class="ui small compact right floated button light"><i aria-hidden="true" class="plus icon"></i>Add</button></div>
            <div class="ui segment" style="padding: 0px;">
              <table class="ui selectable single line table">
                <thead class="">
                  <tr class="left aligned">
                    <th class="">Name</th>
                    <th class="">Description</th>
                    <th class=""></th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="">
                  <tr class="">
                    <td class="">
                      <div class="ui transparent input"><input type="text"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="">
                      <div class="ui transparent input"><input type="text"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td class=""><button class="ui red mini icon button light"><i aria-hidden="true" class="red delete icon"></i></button></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="ui error input"><input type="text"></div>
```

Comment: is that a glitch from semantic ui or semantic creator create this different rule purposely? i don't understand why same class should behave differently

Comment: I don't this this is a glitch as it's meant to be wrapped inside an element with class `.form`.
It's the same classes but it's being affected by different selectors as I explained above.